# GlobalSettings onStart fires only after first request

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1, onstart

I need to run some code only once when I starts the play server. When using the GlobalSettings.OnStart() I notice that the code is executed only after the first (http) request to the server. Any idea how can I run my code just after the server starts and before any request is sent?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is the behavior when the application is in development mode, `play run`. When it's running in production mode, `play start`, then your `onStart` method will run immediately when the application starts prior to any requests.

Comment: Thanks you very much. it answered my question and solved my problem. I wonder if I missed this in the Play documentation as I don't recall seeing this and I read most of the docs.

Comment: What is the motivation for this difference between production and dev?

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate that (or I should say, workaround this unfortunate dichotomous design), by using this plugin, which, I find useful also in general:

`addSbtPlugin("com.jamesward" % "play-auto-refresh" % "0.0.11")` (plugins.sbt)

And no, it is not really currently documented in any right place, that this is how OnStart works.